# Elastic Image Slideshow displays images less than 50% of the intended size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created an "Elastic Image" slideshow for my front page. It works okay. But the images remain fairly small. It would be more appropriate to have the images stretch over the width of the screen.

Is anyone familiar how this can be achieved? I will include the entire code below.

Thank you so much in advance.

First the CSS file:

```css
 
 .ei-slider{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1999px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .ei-slider-loading{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index:999;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 400px;
 }
 .ei-slider-large{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .ei-slider-large li{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .ei-slider-large li img{
  width: 100%;
 }
 .ei-title h4{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: 13%;
  top: 30%;
 }
 
 .ei-title h2, h3{
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: 13%;
  top: 30%;
 }
 
 .ei-title h2, .ei-title h3{
  text-align: right;
 }
 
 .ei-title h4 {
         text-align: left;
 }
 
 .ei-title h2{
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #b5b5b5;
 }
 .ei-title h3{
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
 }
 
 .ei-title h4{
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: 'sans-serif'; italic;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0ffff;
 }
 
 
 
 
 /* the thumbs... */
 
 .ei-slider-thumbs{
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
 }
 .ei-slider-thumbs li{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 10%;
 }
 .ei-slider-thumbs li.ei-slider-element{
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10%;
  z-index: 10;
  text-indent: -9000px;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 }
 .ei-slider-thumbs li a{
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9000px;
  background: #666 ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 
         0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
         0px 1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 
         0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
         0px 1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  box-shadow: 
         0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
         0px 1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease;
     -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease;
     -o-transition: background 0.2s ease;
     -ms-transition: background 0.2s ease;
     transition: background 0.2s ease;
 }
 .ei-slider-thumbs li a:hover{
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
 }
 .ei-slider-thumbs li img{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
     -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
     transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-box-reflect: 
         below 0px -webkit-gradient(
             linear, 
             left top, 
             left bottom, 
             from(transparent), 
             color-stop(50%, transparent), 
             to(rgba(255,255,255,0.3))
             );
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
 }
 .ei-slider-thumbs li:hover img{
  opacity: -1;
  bottom: -1px;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
 }
 
 
 @media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
  .ei-title{
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   top: auto;
   bottom: 10px;
   background: #fff;
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
   padding: 5px 0;
  }
  .ei-title h2, .ei-title h3, .ei-title h4 {
   text-align: center;
  }
  .ei-title h2{
   font-size: 30px;
   line-height: 24px;
  }
  .ei-title h3{
   font-size: 20px;
   line-height: 20px;
  }
  
  .ei-title h4{
   font-size: 10px;
   line-height: 20px;
  }
 }
```

Next, the javascript file:

```js
 
 (function( window, $, undefined ) {
   
   /*
   * smartresize: debounced resize event for jQuery
   *
   * latest version and complete README available on Github:
   * https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.smartresize.js
   *
   * Copyright 2011 @louis_remi
   * Licensed under the MIT license.
   */
  
   var $event = $.event, resizeTimeout;
  
   $event.special.smartresize  = {
    setup: function() {
     $(this).bind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
    },
    teardown: function() {
     $(this).unbind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
    },
    handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
     // Save the context
     var context = this,
      args  = arguments;
  
     // set correct event type
     event.type = "smartresize";
  
     if ( resizeTimeout ) { clearTimeout( resizeTimeout ); }
     resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery.event.handle.apply( context, args );
     }, execAsap === "execAsap"? 0 : 100 );
    }
   };
  
   $.fn.smartresize    = function( fn ) {
    return fn ? this.bind( "smartresize", fn ) : this.trigger( "smartresize", ["execAsap"] );
   };
   
   $.Slideshow     = function( options, element ) {
   
    this.$el   = $( element );
    
    /***** images ****/
    
    // list of image items
    this.$list   = this.$el.find('ul.ei-slider-large');
    // image items
    this.$imgItems  = this.$list.children('li');
    // total number of items
    this.itemsCount  = this.$imgItems.length;
    // images
    this.$images  = this.$imgItems.find('img:first');
    
    /***** thumbs ****/
    
    // thumbs wrapper
    this.$sliderthumbs = this.$el.find('ul.ei-slider-thumbs').hide();
    // slider elements
    this.$sliderElems = this.$sliderthumbs.children('li');
    // sliding div
    this.$sliderElem = this.$sliderthumbs.children('li.ei-slider-element');
    // thumbs
    this.$thumbs  = this.$sliderElems.not('.ei-slider-element');
    
    // initialize slideshow
    this._init( options );
    
   };
   
   $.Slideshow.defaults   = {
    // animation types:
    // "sides" : new slides will slide in from left / right
    // "center": new slides will appear in the center
    animation   : 'sides', // sides || center
    // if true the slider will automatically slide, and it will only stop if the user clicks on a thumb
    autoplay   : false,
    // interval for the slideshow
    slideshow_interval : 3000,
    // speed for the sliding animation
    speed   : 1000,
    // easing for the sliding animation
    easing   : '',
    // percentage of speed for the titles animation. Speed will be speed * titlesFactor
    titlesFactor  : 0.60,
    // titles animation speed
    titlespeed   : 900,
    // titles animation easing
    titleeasing   : '',
    // maximum width for the thumbs in pixels
    thumbMaxWidth  : 150
      };
   
   $.Slideshow.prototype   = {
    _init     : function( options ) {
     
     this.options   = $.extend( true, {}, $.Slideshow.defaults, options );
     
     // set the opacity of the title elements and the image items
     this.$imgItems.css( 'opacity', 0 );
     this.$imgItems.find('div.ei-title > *').css( 'opacity', 0 );
     
     // index of current visible slider
     this.current  = 0;
     
     var _self   = this;
     
     // preload images
     // add loading status
     this.$loading  = $('<div class="ei-slider-loading">Loading</div>').prependTo( _self.$el );
     
     $.when( this._preloadImages() ).done( function() {
      
      // hide loading status
      _self.$loading.hide();
      
      // calculate size and position for each image
      _self._setImagesSize();
      
      // configure thumbs container
      _self._initThumbs();
      
      // show first
      _self.$imgItems.eq( _self.current ).css({
       'opacity'  : 1,
       'z-index' : 10
      }).show().find('div.ei-title > *').css( 'opacity', 1 );
      
      // if autoplay is true
      if( _self.options.autoplay ) {
      
       _self._startSlideshow();
      
      }
      
      // initialize the events
      _self._initEvents();
     
     });
     
    },
    _preloadImages  : function() {
     
     // preloads all the large images
     
     var _self = this,
      loaded = 0;
     
     return $.Deferred(
     
      function(dfd) {
     
       _self.$images.each( function( i ) {
        
        $('<img/>').load( function() {
        
         if( ++loaded === _self.itemsCount ) {
         
          dfd.resolve();
          
         }
        
        }).attr( 'src', $(this).attr('src') );
       
       });
       
      }
      
     ).promise();
     
    },
    _setImagesSize  : function() {
     
     // save ei-slider's width
     this.elWidth = this.$el.width();
     
     var _self = this;
     
     this.$images.each( function( i ) {
      
      var $img = $(this);
       imgDim = _self._getImageDim( $img.attr('src') );
       
      $img.css({
       width  : imgDim.width,
       height  : imgDim.height,
       marginLeft : imgDim.left,
       marginTop : imgDim.top
      });
      
     });
    
    },
    _getImageDim  : function( src ) {
     
     var $img    = new Image();
         
     $img.src    = src;
       
     var c_w  = this.elWidth,
      c_h  = this.$el.height(),
      r_w  = c_h / c_w,
      
      i_w  = $img.width,
      i_h  = $img.height,
      r_i  = i_h / i_w,
      new_w, new_h, new_left, new_top;
       
     if( r_w > r_i ) {
      
      new_h = c_h;
      new_w = c_h / r_i;
     
     }
     else {
     
      new_h = c_w * r_i;
      new_w = c_w;
     
     }
       
     return {
      width : new_w,
      height : new_h,
      left : ( c_w - new_w ) / 2,
      top  : ( c_h - new_h ) / 2
     };
    
    },
    _initThumbs   : function() {
    
     // set the max-width of the slider elements to the one set in the plugin's options
     // also, the width of each slider element will be 100% / total number of elements
     this.$sliderElems.css({
      'max-width' : this.options.thumbMaxWidth + 'px',
      'width'  : 100 / this.itemsCount + '%'
     });
     
     // set the max-width of the slider and show it
     this.$sliderthumbs.css( 'max-width', this.options.thumbMaxWidth * this.itemsCount + 'px' ).show();
     
    },
    _startSlideshow  : function() {
    
     var _self = this;
     
     this.slideshow = setTimeout( function() {
      
      var pos;
      
      ( _self.current === _self.itemsCount - 1 ) ? pos = 0 : pos = _self.current + 1;
      
      _self._slideTo( pos );
      
      if( _self.options.autoplay ) {
      
       _self._startSlideshow();
      
      }
    
     }, this.options.slideshow_interval);
    
    },
    // shows the clicked thumb's slide
    _slideTo   : function( pos ) {
     
     // return if clicking the same element or if currently animating
     if( pos === this.current || this.isAnimating )
      return false;
     
     this.isAnimating = true;
     
     var $currentSlide = this.$imgItems.eq( this.current ),
      $nextSlide  = this.$imgItems.eq( pos ),
      _self   = this,
      
      preCSS   = {zIndex : 10},
      animCSS   = {opacity : 1};
     
     // new slide will slide in from left or right side
     if( this.options.animation === 'sides' ) {
      
      preCSS.left  = ( pos > this.current ) ? -1 * this.elWidth : this.elWidth;
      animCSS.left = 0;
     
     } 
     
     // titles animation
     $nextSlide.find('div.ei-title > h2')
         .css( 'margin-right', 50 + 'px' )
         .stop()
         .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
         .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
         .end()
         .find('div.ei-title > h3')
         .css( 'margin-right', -50 + 'px' )
         .stop()
         .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
         .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
     
     $.when(
      
      // fade out current titles
      $currentSlide.css( 'z-index' , 1 ).find('div.ei-title > *').stop().fadeOut( this.options.speed / 2, function() {
       // reset style
       $(this).show().css( 'opacity', 0 ); 
      }),
      
      // animate next slide in
      $nextSlide.css( preCSS ).stop().animate( animCSS, this.options.speed, this.options.easing ),
      
      // "sliding div" moves to new position
      this.$sliderElem.stop().animate({
       left : this.$thumbs.eq( pos ).position().left
      }, this.options.speed )
      
     ).done( function() {
      
      // reset values
      $currentSlide.css( 'opacity' , 0 ).find('div.ei-title > *').css( 'opacity', 0 );
       _self.current = pos;
       _self.isAnimating  = false;
      
      });
      
    },
    _initEvents   : function() {
     
     var _self = this;
     
     // window resize
     $(window).on( 'smartresize.eislideshow', function( event ) {
      
      // resize the images
      _self._setImagesSize();
     
      // reset position of thumbs sliding div
      _self.$sliderElem.css( 'left', _self.$thumbs.eq( _self.current ).position().left );
     
     });
     
     // click the thumbs
     this.$thumbs.on( 'click.eislideshow', function( event ) {
      
      if( _self.options.autoplay ) {
      
       clearTimeout( _self.slideshow );
       _self.options.autoplay = false;
      
      }
      
      var $thumb = $(this),
       idx  = $thumb.index() - 1; // exclude sliding div
       
      _self._slideTo( idx );
      
      return false;
     
     });
     
    }
   };
   
   var logError     = function( message ) {
    
    if ( this.console ) {
     
     console.error( message );
     
    }
    
   };
   
   $.fn.eislideshow   = function( options ) {
   
    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
    
     var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
  
     this.each(function() {
     
      var instance = $.data( this, 'eislideshow' );
      
      if ( !instance ) {
       logError( "cannot call methods on eislideshow prior to initialization; " +
       "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
       return;
      }
      
      if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
       logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for eislideshow instance" );
       return;
      }
      
      instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
     
     });
    
    } 
    else {
    
     this.each(function() {
     
      var instance = $.data( this, 'eislideshow' );
      if ( !instance ) {
       $.data( this, 'eislideshow', new $.Slideshow( options, this ) );
      }
     
     });
    
    }
    
    return this;
    
   };
   
  })( window, jQuery );
```

And finally, the HTML:

```html
 
  <div class="wrapper">
                 <div id="ei-slider" class="ei-slider">
                     <ul class="ei-slider-large">
       <li>
                             <img src="uploads/2016/01/slider-3.jpg" alt="image01">
                             <div class="ei-title">
                                 <h2>High end Management Tools</h2>
                                 <h3>Available at your fingertips!</h3>
                                 <h4>With the available technologies, we provide the methods and tools that will help society to excel to new heights</h4>
                             </div>
                         </li>
                         <li>
                             <img src="uploads/2016/01/about-1.jpg" alt="image02" />
                             <div class="ei-title">
                                 <h2>Enterprises, Administration Managers</h2>
                                 <h3>Improve your Performance!</h3>
                                 <h4>Regardless of your position, we have the solutions for all levels of professionals, and students alike.... </h4>
                             </div>
                         </li>
                         <li>
                             <img src="uploads/2016/01/home-parallax.jpg" alt="image03" />
                             <div class="ei-title">
                                 <h2>Stunning Solutions</h2>
                                 <h3>For Remarkable results!</h3>
                                 <h4>We are bringing today's technology to assist the traditional family with promising results.</h4>
                             </div>
                         </li>
                         
                     </ul><!-- ei-slider-large -->
 
  </div><!-- ei-slider -->
            
         </div><!-- wrapper -->
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.eislideshow.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
             $('#ei-slider').eislideshow({
     animation   : 'center',
     autoplay   : true,
     slideshow_interval : 6000,
     titlesFactor  : 0
             });
         });
     </script>
```

Comment: Please use a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: OK. will that work? https://jsfiddle.net/1630zd2a/1/